# Can a chordal skip double another voice?

Tags: voice-leading, satb

[image]

Here the soprano skips to the alto's C# on the second beat forming a unison. Is there anything wrong with this kind of skip or would it be perfectly correct voice leading?

Comment: Also check your tenor and bass going into beat 3.

Comment: what about them?

Comment: Bass and tenor (and now I notice alto does it to) descend to G# and D#.  They're hidden/direct fifths and octaves, btu all three voices going hat way isn't ideal.

Comment: direct 5ths and octaves are no problem in 4 part writing unless it is between bass and soprano and only if they leap

Comment: Perhaps, but I'd avoid having that many voices arrive on 5th/8ve in the same direction.  Whether or not it's technically allowed aside, it certainly will give the appearance of parallel fifths

Answer (score 3):

Both the soprano and alto doubling that C♯ is not a problem. However, how you move from that doubled pitch does create an issue.

Notice that, on beat 3, the soprano goes below the pitch that the alto just had. This is an example of **voice overlap**, defined as when one voice exceeds the boundary of a neighboring voice in an adjacent chord.

Voice overlap is similar to voice crossing, when (for example) the soprano is placed underneath the current alto pitch. But voice crossing occurs in a single chord, whereas voice overlap is a phenomenon that occurs over two chords.

Had your soprano stayed on or above this C♯, however, there would be no error.

Comment: Had my Soprano stayed on F# it still would have gone below the alto in the next chord wouldnt it? The alto is C# and the B on chord 3 is lower than that.

Comment: @armani Yes, correct! That is to say that the error already existed, and wasn't made worse by the chordal skip.